# How to upload from Digital Ocean Storage to Google Cloud Storage, directly, programatically without rclone

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I want to migrate files from Digital Ocean Storage into Google Cloud Storage programatically without rclone.

I know the exact location file that resides in the Digital Ocean Storage(DOS), and I have the signed url for the Google Cloud Storage(GCS).

How can I modify the following code so I can copy the DOS file directly into GCS without intermediate download to my computer ?

```
def upload_to_gcs_bucket(blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
    """ Upload data to a bucket"""

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'creds.json')

    #print(buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)

    #returns a public url
    return blob.public_url
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't. There is no interface/API between Google Cloud Storage and other cloud storage services. There are services that can do this for you (see @dazwilkin answer) but in summary, you must download and then upload using a service (yours or another). To improve performance, use a VM in the cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's [Storage Transfer Servivce](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service) should be an answer for this type of problem (particularly because [DigitalOcean Spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/spaces) like most is S3-compatible. But (!) I think (I'm unfamiliar with it and unsure) it can't be used for this configuration.

There is no way to transfer files from a source to a destination **without** some form of intermediate transfer but what you can do is use memory rather than using file storage as the intermediary. Memory is generally more constrained than file storage **and** if you wish to run multiple transfers concurrently, each will consume some amount of storage.

It's curious that you're using Signed URLs. Generally Signed URLs are provided by a 3rd-party to limit access to 3rd-party buckets. If you own the destination bucket, then it will be easier to use Google Cloud Storage buckets directly from one of Google's client libraries, such as [Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

The Python examples include uploading from [file and from memory](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object). It will likely be best to stream the files into Cloud Storage if you'd prefer to not create intermediate files. Here's a [Python example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#prereq-code-samples)